# checking that an event fired with mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, polymer, mocha.js, web-component-tester

How can I test that an element fired an event with mocha? I've got an ugly solution working, but it's not very readable, takes a long time to time out when it fails, and doesn't give good failure messaging.

```
describe('test-element', function() {
  var el;

  beforeEach(function() {
    el = document.createElement('test-element');
  });

  it('fires a save event', function(done) {
    el.addEventListener('save', function() {
      done();
    });
    el.save();
  });
```

In a perfect world, I think something like this would be cooler.

```
  it('fires a save event', function() {
    el.save();
    expect(el).to.have.firedEvent('save');
  });
});
```

Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better approach or a custom matcher library I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about spying on the `fire` function...?

Not sure what stubbing/spying library you're using but lets say [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/). So something like...

```
var spy = sinon.spy(el, 'fire');
el.save();
expect(spy.calledWith('save')).to.be.true;
```